# How to indent a line starting from the position of the cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to indent a line partially in vim, starting from the cursor. For example: I have the line

```
var array = []
```

with cursor positioned on `=`.

And I want to get something like this as a result

```
var array           = []
```

Comment: you want to change your tab indentation?

Comment: What's wrong with Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155) does that.

In your example, to align the `=` and following to column 20, use `20<Leader>le`.

---

For aligning multiple instances, also look into [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) or the alternative [Tabular - Vim script for text filtering and alignment](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular).

Comment: I'm personally fond of [EasyAlign](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520) which I found much easier to use than Align. I haven't tried Tabular.

Comment: Thanks, tabularize has all the tools I need!